# Using BeautifulSoup only consider a certain part of contents of a webpage

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, html

How can I have BeautifulSoup only consider a certain part of contents of a webpage?

For example I want to pick up all `div` tags *only* after the ‘Most viewed right now’ on the page http://www.dailypress.com/.

It goes:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

url = ' http://www.dailypress.com/ '
page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.read())
```

and I can use:

```
str(soup).find(' Most viewed right now')
```

to locate the sentence, however it’s not helpful in determining the part of the contents I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find the `div` that contains the most viewed articles and find all links inside:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> import urllib2
>>> import re
>>> url = "http://www.dailypress.com"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))
>>> most_viewed = soup.find('div', class_=re.compile('mostViewed'))
>>> for item in most_viewed.find_all('a'):
...     print item.text.strip()
... 
Body of driver recovered from Chesapeake Bay Bridge-Tunnel wreck
Hampton police looking for man linked to Friday's fatal apartment shooting
Police identify suspect in Saturday's fatal shooting in Hampton
Teen spice user: 'It's the new crack'
When spice came to Gloucester
```

The trick here is that we are first finding the container for `Most Viewed` links - it is a `div` that has `mostViewed` class. You can inspect it with the help of browser developer tools.

Comment: thanks alecxe. by the way, what if there isn't a class 'mostViewed' but only a line of text 'Most viewed right now' on webpage?

Comment: @MarkK then you could have used css selectors, or just get the parent and find all of the children with a `div` tag. Or, switch to `lxml` and use xpath expression. Well, a lot of options really.